# Setting cutoff for computing betweenness centrality in NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx, node-centrality

I'm using NetworkX to analyze a graph and compute the betweenness centrality for its nodes. I would like to set a specific cutoff for the shortest path length to control the calculation of betweenness centrality.

However, it seems that NetworkX's betweenness_centrality function does not have a built-in parameter for directly setting the cutoff. I'm wondering if there is a way to achieve this cutoff effect in NetworkX when computing betweenness centrality.

Is there any way to modify the source code of networkX's betweennness_centrlaity function  to set the cutoff for betweenness centrality in NetworkX?